# Trying to login to T-Mobile with casper.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, adobe, casperjs

I'm trying to login to T-mobile with casperjs and I get `page errors` that you can see below.

It looks like it was successfully submit because i think it got redirected to the home page after logging in. But it didn't find `mboxCreate` don't know what that is. I think it is an Adobe product.

EDIT: I noticed that when the page loads, sections of the page do ajax requests and when it is done the class with `firstname` appears. I thought I could just wait for it but maybe I have to handle these ajax requests.

**

```
Page Error: [Target] Classic: Content container not found: mboxCreate("tmobile_g
lobal")
[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 4520ms.
Page Error: [Target] executeAjax(): timeout: timeout
```

**

Can you help me with this error

```
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 5/6 https://account.t-mobile.com/oauth2/v1/auth
(HTTP 200)
[info] [remote] attempting to fetch form element from selector: 'form.login-form
'
[debug] [remote] Set "username" field value to redacted@redacted.com
[debug] [remote] Set "password" field value to *********
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mousedown' on selector: input.login-btn
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'mouseup' on selector: input.login-btn
[debug] [phantom] Mouse event 'click' on selector: input.login-btn
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 5/6: done in 43563ms.
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 6/6 https://account.t-mobile.com/oauth2/v1/auth
(HTTP 200)
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 6/6: done in 43574ms.
[info] [phantom] Step _step 7/7 https://account.t-mobile.com/oauth2/v1/auth (HTT
P 200)
[info] [phantom] Step _step 7/7: done in 43595ms.
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://my.t-mobile.com/?code=01.Xts
2p0zGDIdDOlo4p, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://my.t-mobile.com/home.html, t
ype=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "https://my.t-mobile.com/home.html"
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
Page Error: [Target] Classic: Content container not found: mboxCreate("tmobile_g
lobal")
[info] [phantom] waitFor() finished in 4520ms.
Page Error: [Target] executeAjax(): timeout: timeout
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://tmobile.demdex.net/dest5.htm
l?d_nsid=undefined#https%3A%2F%2Fmy.t-mobile.com%2Fhome.html, type=Other, willNa
vigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://lpcdn.lpsnmedia.net/le_secur
e_storage/storage.cross.domain.min.html?loc=https%3A%2F%2Fmy.t-mobile.com&site=6
2258097&asmr=15&env=prod, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://62258097.va.cobrowse.liveper
son.net/js/synchronite/webagent/libs/lpSecureStorage/storage.min.html?loc=https%
3A%2F%2Fmy.t-mobile.com&site=62258097&ist=sessionStorage, type=Other, willNaviga
te=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://d.agkn.com/iframe/7641/?ordi
d=&type=10000&uid=30417548914274197053738572246119955072, type=Other, willNaviga
te=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://fls.doubleclick.net/activity
i;src=998766;type=096ca001;cat=mytsu689;ord=9373055989854.037?, type=Other, will
Navigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://tmobile.demdex.net/dest5.htm
l?d_nsid=0#https%3A%2F%2Fmy.t-mobile.com%2Fhome.html, type=Other, willNavigate=t
rue, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://gateway.answerscloud.com/tmo
bile/production/foresee/fs.frame.html?d=my.t-mobile.com&v=R0371D9C424, type=Othe
r, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://998766.fls.doubleclick.net/a
ctivityi;dc_pre=CL3onP6fuNACFSe_swodZdYH_w;src=998766;type=096ca001;cat=mytsu689
;ord=9373055989854.037, type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false
[debug] [phantom] Automatically injected jquery.js client side
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 8/8 https://my.t-mobile.com/home.html (HTTP 200)

TITLE:
[info] [phantom] Step anonymous 8/8: done in 181469ms.
[info] [phantom] Done 8 steps in 181483ms
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=about:blank, type=Other, willNavigat
e=true, isMainFrame=true
[debug] [phantom] url changed to "about:blank"
```

My code:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    verbose : true,
    logLevel : "debug",
//     remoteScripts:  [
//     'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js'
// ]
    clientScripts : ["jquery.js"]
});

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36')

var loginTmobileUrl = "https://account.t-mobile.com/oauth2/v1/auth";
var alexa = "https://www.alexa.com/secure/login?resource=%2Fpro%2Fscreener"
casper.on("error", function(msg){
    this.echo("error: " + msg, "Error");
})
casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace){
    this.echo("Page Error: " + msg, "error");
});
casper.start(loginTmobileUrl, function(){
    casper.waitForSelector("form.login-form", function(){
        console.log("form found!!");
    })
});
casper.then(function(){
    this.fillSelectors("form.login-form", {
        "input#username" : "jack2ky@yahoo.com",
        "input#password" : "daddy1234"
    });
    casper.click("input.login-btn");
})

casper.then(function(){
    casper.waitForSelector(".firstName", function(){
        console.log("TITLE:  " + document.title);

        casper.evaluate(function(){
            if($(".firstName").length){
                console.log("FIRSTNAME FOUND");
                console.log("NAME:: " + $(".firstName").text());
            }else{
                console.log("FIRST NAME NOT FOUND");
            }

        })

    })

})


casper.run();
```

Comment: Maybe a cross site scripting error?